# How to find min and max value for each column in the entire csv file

Tags: java, csv, max, min

How to find min and max value for each column (except albhabet values)in a csv file.

```
I want to get each columns min and max values

5.3,3.6,1.6,0.3,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.3,1.6,0.3,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.3,1.3,0.3,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.3,1.6,0.0,Iris-setosa

col 1, min = 4.6 ,max = 5.3
col 2, min = 3.3 ,max = 3.6
col 3, min = 1.3 ,max = 1.6
col 4, min = 0.0 ,max = 0.3
```

What I did is ,I iterated through each line and stored each column in a hashmap

```
{1=[5.3,4.9,4.9,4.6],2=[3.6,3.3,3.3,3.3],3[1.6,1.6,1.3,1.6],4[0.3,0.3,0.3,0.0]}
```

Then I calculated

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {      
// Iterating through values
String key = entry.getKey();
List<String> values = entry.getValue();
min = Double.parseDouble(Collections.min(values));
max = Double.parseDouble(Collections.max(values));
}
```

But when large data is coming it is not better to hold that much data in hashmap
Then find the min and max
How can I find min/max in other way.

**Update**

```
String line[] = value.split(delimit);
for(int i=0;i<line.length -1;i++){
 if (Double.parseDouble(line[i] ) < min) { 
   min = Double.parseDouble(line[i] );
  }
 if (Double.parseDouble(line[i] ) > max) {
  max = Double.parseDouble(line[i] );
  }
}
```

Not getting the expected result.

**Solution** :[Calculating min and max of columns in a csv file](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/calculating-min-and-max-of-columns-in.html)

Comment: with your update you are converting a LINE to DOUBLE... think about it, witch number is "4.9,3.3,1.6,0.3,Iris-setosa"?. You have to SPLIT (again) the line to cells, then parse this cells to Double.. also min and max cannot be one variable, but an array with size of the number of column (every column will have a min and max)
IMHO you should read the file line by line and split every line by cells divider, not read all file and then split by line divider and then split by cell divider, because file bigger tahn ram size for your program will crash it. reading line by line keep your ram usage low.

Comment: for each column I need min and max values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

- Read the file using a Stream.
- Read data line by line.
- split the columns.
- create a method to calculate the max and the min.

so it could look like this:

```
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] columns= line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            calculateMinAndMax(columns);

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Then create a method to calculate min and max

```
private double[] maxValues = {0, 0, 0, 0};
private double[] minValues = {0, 0, 0, 0};
private void calculateMinAndMax(String[] line) {
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
            //check the max value
            double currentValue = Double.Double.parseDouble(line[i]);
            if(currentValue > maxValues[i] ) {
                maxValues[i] = currentValue;
            }

            //check the min value
            if(currentValue < minValues[i]) {
                minValues[i] = currentValue;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I tried this I am only getting the lines min and max value

Comment: i don't know what have you tried by you can go as my updated answer.

Comment: Salah i think he want to save not only the value but all the line. also seconds if in calculateMinAndMax is wrong.
@UnmeshaSreeVeni to get all the line, save it when the code save min and max value! because calculateMinAndMax uses an array of string (witch is a string for each column of current line), you have to save the result in an array (size = number of column to check) of array of string (size = number of column)

Comment: for each column I need min and max value

Comment: Then this is the right solution. You just have to size maxValues and minValues as the number of your columns, and print them at the end of the program

Comment: When i did the above code I am getting a min max value as 0.0

Comment: @UnmeshaSreeVeni the code above will give you the right max for each column, but the min will always 0.0 because we have set the mix array with initial value 0.0, and there were no value less than 0.0 from the file. to avoid that you need to initialize the min arrays value with the first line values. that should work just fine.

Comment: Am I able to get the min and max in a list so that i neednot want to know the arraysize in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. Split() each line based on ","
2. from the array got after using split(), ignore/delete the last cell/index.
3. Sort the array.
4. In the sorted array, get min and max values.

put steps 1-4 in a loop until -"you have more lines in the file ".
Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about large set of data you should inline the process as much possible.

In your case you have a source that is divided in two items. A line and elements. You can use class [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

```
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(source);

        while(lineScanner.hasNext()) {

            Scanner elementScanner = new Scanner(lineScanner.nextLine()).useDelimiter(",");

            for(int column = 1; elementScanner.hasNextDouble(); column++) {

                double nextDouble = elementScanner.nextDouble();

                updateMax(column, nextDouble); //or updateMinMax(column,nextDouble);
                updateMin(column, nextDouble);

            }

        }

    lineScanner.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why create an array/list/set when you can find the max/min for every cell WHILE REDING the line?

1. read a line
2. split it
3. convert cells to double and check for min/max
4. next line

with only one cicle you have your result. You can also store the results into array/list/set for other elaboration, but that is not necessary (and slow, as array/list/set will probably have to be resized many times if file size is not know at the beginning, also RAM size will be much buigger,all data vs just min/max variable for each cell)